# If I delete Clash of Clans on one iPad, and download it on another using the same Apple ID, will it save my progress?

Tags: game-center, clash-of-clans

I just bought a new iPad and I’m wondering if I can move Clash of Clans from the old to the new and save the progress. I spent a fair bit of money into it and I don't want to lose it.

Answer (score 3):

Extracted from the [Clash of Clans FAQ](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ_and_Support):

> **Can I continue my game on a new device?**
>
> Yes you can, but it requires the use of GameCenter. The only way to transfer your account to a new device is to have the original village linked to a Game Center account. Login to that Game Center account on your new device and you will prompted to load your previous village.

[This](https://forum.supercell.com/showthread.php/19716-**Setting-up-a-new-iOS-device-with-your-old-game-(AKA-always-connect-to-GameCenter)**) post which requires a login, has some helpful instructions on setting up your game on a new device.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you can **transfer In-app purchases between devices**:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4009

> Subscriptions and replenishable In-App Purchase cannot be transferred
>   or synced to another iOS device. Non-replenishable In-App Purchases 
>   and auto-renewing subscriptions can be transferred to another iOS
>   device authorized with your iTunes Store account. For example, if you
>   transfer a game from an iPhone to an iPod touch, only the game levels
>   will sync over, the extra ammo and experience points will not be
>   transferred.

**Re-downloading In-App** purchases for free depends on the App:

> If you lose your In-App Purchases because apps were accidentally
>   deleted, or if you had to restore your device without a backup, you
>   may be able to download some of your in app purchases again for free.
>   Not all In-App Purchases are eligible for free download again.
>
> Replenishable In-App Purchases and subscriptions cannot be downloaded
>   again for free, and must be repurchased. Examples include but are not
>   limited to: extra ammo, additional health, extra experience points, or
>   other one-time services.  Non-replenishable In-App Purchases and
>   auto-renewing subscriptions can be downloaded again for free. Examples
>   include: bonus game levels, a map/city guide, a daily news
>   subscription, or other recurring services.  To download an In-App
>   Purchase again, you must download it from within the installed app
>   using the same iTunes Store account name for the original In-App
>   Purchase.

Answer (score -3):

Game center is the best way try it out ok hope this help

Comment: Trying it out and then see it working will not really help the asker. How do you propose he should proceed without running the risk of losing progress data?